# DataTables Warning: Please assist

Tags: mysql

I have created a family tree on my website using MySQL 5. Everything is working except the User Administration table. When I attempt to access it I get an error that says (DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see datatables.net/tn/1). When I use the chrome debugger to find out what is happening it is telling me (The requested URL was rejected. If you think this is an error, please contact the webmaster).

I have contacted the family tree developer to find out what is wrong and they are telling me the issue is in the underlying table on the server end and not their software as it won't produce that type of error. When I contact my hosting site, they tell me they need to be able to reproduce the error and I have no idea where it is in the MySQL software. My hosting site will not work with 3rd party software. So I have to diagnose this on my own. I have no clue what to do. I have looked at your other threads and turned of all firewalls on my computer and I still get the error. I have also tried clearing cookies and cache and still get the error. Are there any other things I can try? Or something I can tell my hosting company to look for?

Comment: So I understand that you hired someone to the develop your site and now you have a problem when installing the code in your server. In that case, the question is off-topic here (sorry), but I can see that the error message is not directly related to the database as is not a MySQL error. Following the link included in the error it seems to be produced by a package named DataTables that is for manipulating HTML tables, not database tables.

Comment: No, that is not the case. I developed my own website. What I am doing is using a program called Webtrees (Webtrees.net). I have set up the webpage and placed their files and folders onto my server. I created a MySQL database for those files and folders to interact with. I am getting this error because of an issue with an underlying table.

Comment: From what Webtrees users are telling me this is because of a permission setting in the database itself. They say its caused by “mod-security” plugin on the server. It has a setting that regards URLs containing things like “admin-users” as hacking. The fix is to disable that rule. However, I cannot figure out how to get to those rules and my hosting site, who is the one that controls the database, has no clue how to do it either.

Comment: Your two comments contains a lot of information that should be included in the original question, because that info make the question a lot more clear. You should edit the question to include it, but I'm afraid the the question is still offtopic because is not about programming but about server configuration. I think that you could have better options of getting the question answered in the sister site [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), which is for server administrators, but don't forget to include the detailed information.

Comment: Also `mod_security`is not related with mysql, but with the HTTP server. Based on the error message and in your explanation I think that the error is not directly related with the database (the tables mentioned in the error are not database tables but HTML tables. Also you could try posting the question in [ProWebmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)